# Visual Studio 2013 Setting up a class?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I need to create a class in visual studio. However when I add a class it creates two files: name.h and name.cpp I don't know which one that I insert the main code into. Also once I have created this class I am assuming in my main file I can just use:

```
#include <name.h>
```

To include it and then just type the name of the class to use it in my code?

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: What is "the main code"? Normally the class declaration goes in the header, and the definition (member function bodies) goes in the .cpp.

Comment: Kind of a noob, guess I mean the default file it creates that you put int main() etc. Don't really know what it is called sorry

Comment: What about starting off with a basic book that covers such topics?

Comment: @Unlogical: Ah, normally the definition for `main` goes into a .cpp file just for that (there's no "class" associated with `main`, unlike in, say, Java or C#). You can add an empty stand-alone .cpp file by right clicking on the Source Files folder in the solution explorer, choosing 'Add->New Item', then choosing 'C++ File'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the definition of the class in `name.h`.

```
class name
{
  // Class member functions.
   name();
   ~name();

   // class member data.
   std::string n_;
};
```

Add the implementations of the member functions in `name.cpp`

```
#include <name.h>

name::name() : n_("defaultName")
   // Add code to initialize the member data in the 
{
}

name::~name()
{
}
```

You asked:

> To include it and then just type the name of the class to use it in my code?

Yes.

Answer (score 1):

`name.cpp` is for your main source code. 
The `name.h` is a **header** file which provides an "interface" (here the interface is for name.cpp) so that you can access the code from other cpp files and keep the implementation.
 The `#include` statement is used to include files; the compiler essentially replaces the include statement with the contents of the file when the code is compiled.